# Video Sequencer-Add Transition-Wipe don't works （version3.1.0）

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I follow some tutorials using wipe in Video Sequencer,it should looks like this
[image]

But when I do the same thing,it looks like this,no wipe effect
[image]

I just add two strips,add wipe,and do nothing else.The only difference is all tutorials are blender2.8~3.0,but what I use is 3.1.Is it a bug,or I have do something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes I think there's a bug, have you tried with a previous version?

Comment: I'm quite sure it's a bug, too. I tried exactly the same thing in 3.1 and 3.0.1, in 3.0.1 it works but in 3.1 it doesn't.

Comment: I don't install previous version,but I ask a friend before I came here,his 3.1 has the same problem.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann wish it will be fixed in the near future,it's a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which have been fixed a few days ago: https://developer.blender.org/rB0603b0804ccd079dfcb5cd881aa1a8e50e33a90a